# How can the operation on the homotopic classes be defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the page 322 Munkres described the operation between two homotopic classes as $[f]*[g] = [f*g]$. There I found if $f' * g' \in [f]*[g]$. Then $f' \equiv f$ and $g' \equiv g$ then $f'*g' \equiv f*g$. $\implies$ $[f]*[g] \subseteq [f*g]$.

But I find difficulty to prove the reverse inclusion. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no inclusion.  You are just checking that it is defined independent of choice of representative (which it is).

Comment: But how can I prove that two sets are equal then?

Comment: What two sets?  Do you mean $[f * g]$ and $[f' * g']$?  Glue the homotopies $f' \sim f$ and $g' \sim g$ to get a homotopy $f * g \sim f'*g'$.  By symmetry, you're done.

Comment: But how can I prove the other way round i.e. if $f'*g'$ is homotopic to $f*g$ then $f'*g' \in [f]*[g]$? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Symmetry.  $f*g \sim f' * g'$ implies $f' * g' \sim f * g$.

Comment: You don't really need that, though.  $\alpha \in [\beta]$ implies $[\alpha] = [\beta]$ for any equivalence relation ever, not just homotopy.  You don't need to prove it both ways.

Comment: Suppose $f'*g'$ is homotopic to $f*g$ then obviously $f*g \in [f]*[g]$ . But does this imply $f'*g' \in [f]*[g]$? How can I say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the definition.  The statement $[f]*[g]=[f*g]$ is  *definition* of the notation $[f]*[g]$, not a theorem you have to prove.  The notation $[f]*[g]$ has no meaning before you give this definition, and so it would be meaningless to prove it anyways.  In particular, $[f]*[g]$ is NOT defined as the set $\{f'*g':f'\in [f],g'\in [g]\}$ as you appear to believe.

The only thing you do have to prove is that this is well-defined: in other words, our definition of $[f]*[g]$ doesn't depend on the choice of representatives $f$ and $g$ in the equivalence classes $[f]$ and $[g]$.  That means you want to prove that if $[f']=[f]$ and $[g']=[g]$, then $[f'*g']=[f*g]$, so that the definitions of $[f]*[g]$ and $[f']*[g']$ are equal.  This is exactly what you've done already, so you're done.

Comment: I have understood it now. Thank you very much @Eric Wofsey.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f \sim f'$ via $H: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$, so $H(x,0)=f(x)$, $H(x,1)=f'(x)$, $H(0,t)=f(0)=f'(0)$ and $H(1,t)=f(1)=f'(1)$.  Suppose all the same stuff for $g \sim g'$ via $K$.  (I'm assuming $g(0)=f(1)$, etc.)

Define $L: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ by $L(x,t) = \begin{cases} H(2x, t), & 0 \leq x \leq 1/2\\ K(2x-1,t), & 1/2 \leq x \leq 1.\end{cases}$

Check that $L$ is a homotopy $f*g \sim f'*g'$.  This proves that 
$$
[f *g ] = [f'*g'].
$$
So, $[f]*[g] = [f']*[g']$ whenever $[f]=[f']$ and $[g]=[g']$.  Done.

Comment: This is clearly not what the question is asking about...